# AWK: how can I tell where column begins

Tags: text-processing, awk

After parsing the input line, awk provides access to the original line (`$0`) as well as to each individual column (`$1`, `$2`, ...). While performing this process (lazily, on demand) - it knows exactly the position of the character where the 2nd column starts.

1. Does it provide access to this info (i.e., at what position in the original line $0 does the 2nd column start)?
2. If not - is there any sane/elegant way of finding it out properly? (I'm about to start coding an ugly and inefficient way of mimicking awk's internal behavior by using dynamic-regexps based on `FS`, handling special `FS==" "` case, using capturing groups, etc. But wanted your advice before I dive deep into it.)

---

Example 1 (default FS):

```
$ echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t"\
|awk -F" " '{print "FS:["FS"]";for(i=0;i<=5;i++)if(""!=$i)print "$"i":["$i"]"}'\
|sed 's/\t/\\t/g'

FS:[ ]
$0:[ \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t]
$1:[First]
$2:[Second]
$3:[Third]
```

in here - I need to know that the 2nd column (`Second`) starts with the letter `S` and this is the **13th** character in the input line (so I would be able to store `First` as the key, and preserve/store the `Second \t Third  \t` intact as the value for the further use)

---

Example 2 (TAB as FS):

```
$ echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t"\
|awk -F"\t" '{print "FS:["FS"]";for(i=0;i<=5;i++)if(""!=$i)print "$"i":["$i"]"}'\
|sed 's/\t/\\t/g'

FS:[\t]
$0:[ \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t]
$1:[ ]
$2:[First ]
$4:[  Second ]
$5:[ Third  ]
```

in here - I need to know that the 2nd column (`First`) starts with the letter `F` and this is the **3rd** character in the input line - so I would be able to store   (space) as the key, and preserve/store `First \t\t  Second \t Third  \t` intact as the value for the further use

---

Example 3 (custom FS):

```
$ echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t"\
|awk -F"[ \t]+" '{print "FS:["FS"]";for(i=0;i<=5;i++)if(""!=$i)print "$"i":["$i"]"}'\
|sed 's/\t/\\t/g'

FS:[[ \t]+]
$0:[ \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t]
$2:[First]
$3:[Second]
$4:[Third]
```

in here - I need to know that the 2nd column (`First`) starts with the letter `F` and this is the **3rd** character in the input line - so I would know the 1st column is an empty string, and store the `First \t\t  Second \t Third  \t` as the value for the further use

---

Example 4 (complex FS):

```
$ echo "-11...22;,;..;33-44...;"\
|awk -F"[^0-9-]+" '{print "FS:["FS"]";for(i=0;i<=5;i++)if(""!=$i)print "$"i":["$i"]"}'

FS:[[^0-9-]+]
$0:[-11...22;,;..;33-44...;]
$1:[-11]
$2:[22]
$3:[33-44]
```

in here - I need to know that the 2nd column (`22`) starts with the character `2` and this is the **7th** character in the input line - so I would be able to store `-11` as the key, and `22;,;..;33-44...;` as the value for the further use

---

Basically the idea is to grab some (1st) columns for a custom use and to preserve (store into a variable) the remainder of the line (from 2nd column till end of line) intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always going to use `$1` as the key and the rest of the line (from `$2`) as the value, then you could use `index` to find where they are in `$0`:

1. Use `index` to get the location of `$1` in `$2`
2. Then use the length of `$1` to get the substring of `$0` where the first position where `$2` can be (for cases where `$1` can contain a copy of `$2`)
3. Then use `index` again to get the location of `$2`, so that we can extract the substring starting at `$2`.

Example:

```c
# foo.awk
function mysplit(array) {
    pos1 = index($0, $1)
    sub1 = substr($0, pos1 + length($1))
    pos2 = index(sub1, $2)
    sub2 = substr(sub1, pos2)
    array[$1] = sub2
}

{mysplit(arr)}

END {
    for (i in arr) {
        printf "[%s]:   |%s|\n", i, arr[i]
    }
}
```

With your examples:

```
% echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t" | awk -f foo.awk -F " " | sed 's/\t/\\t/g'
[First]:   |Second \t Third  \t|
% echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t" | awk -f foo.awk -F "\t" | sed 's/\t/\\t/g'
[ ]:   |First \t\t  Second \t Third  \t|
% echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t" | awk -f foo.awk -F "[ \t]+" | sed 's/\t/\\t/g'
[]:   |First \t\t  Second \t Third  \t|
```

Comment: will not work for some weird/extreme/uncommon field separators - `echo AbAAbB | awk -f foo.awk -FAb` will output `[]:   |AbAAbB|` (instead of `[]:   |AAbB|`), but is more-than-good for all my possible use-cases, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In GNU/awk, you can use `split()` with the optional `seps` argument, then iterate over `array` and `seps` to generate `start` and `size` arrays for each field, accumulating the length of each field and separator.

This code is for GNU/awk. The function Offsets() takes a text string and a pattern for the field separators, and returns a pair of arrays containing the start column and length of the fields.

```
$ cat myCols
#! /bin/bash

myCols () {

    local Awk='
BEGIN { cmdDu = "od -A n -t a"; }
#.. Debug the input.
function Debug (tx, Local ) {
    printf ("\nLine %2d: %s\n", NR, tx);
    printf ("%s", tx) | cmdDu; close (cmdDu);
}
#.. Return arrays of column start and length.
function Offsets (col, lth, tx, re, Local, fld, sep, f) {
    delete col; delete lth;
    split (tx, fld, re, sep);
    c = length (sep[0]);
    for (f = 1; f in fld; ++f) {
        col[f] = 1 + c; lth[f] = length (fld[f]);
        c += length (fld[f]) + length (sep[f]);
    }
}
#.. Find fields and show the results.
function Fields (tx, re, Local, col, lth, f) {
    Offsets( col, lth, tx, re);
    for (f = 1; f in col; ++f) {
        printf ("Field %d col %3d lth %3d >%s<\n",
            f, col[f], lth[f], substr (tx, col[f], lth [f]));
    }
}
{ Debug( $0); }
NR == 1 { Fields( $0, ",[[:space:]]*"); }
NR == 2 { Fields( $0, FS); }
'
    awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" )

}

    {
        echo "Never,   Ever,  Forget,  but maybe,   Forgive"
        echo -n -e " \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t"
    } | myCols
```

And test it:

```
$ ./myCols

Line  1: Never,   Ever,  Forget,  but maybe,   Forgive
   N   e   v   e   r   ,  sp  sp  sp   E   v   e   r   ,  sp  sp
   F   o   r   g   e   t   ,  sp  sp   b   u   t  sp   m   a   y
   b   e   ,  sp  sp  sp   F   o   r   g   i   v   e
Field 1 col   1 lth   5 >Never<
Field 2 col  10 lth   4 >Ever<
Field 3 col  17 lth   6 >Forget<
Field 4 col  26 lth   9 >but maybe<
Field 5 col  39 lth   7 >Forgive<

Line  2:    First         Second     Third      
  sp  ht   F   i   r   s   t  sp  ht  ht  sp  sp   S   e   c   o
   n   d  sp  ht  sp   T   h   i   r   d  sp  sp  ht
Field 1 col   3 lth   5 >First<
Field 2 col  13 lth   6 >Second<
Field 3 col  22 lth   5 >Third<
$
```

If you want the exact original string starting from (say) the third field, use:

```
if (3 in col) Tail = substr (tx, col[3]);
```

Comment: perfectly works, upvoted, but accepted another solution because of performance - see my separate answer, thanks

Comment: @Vlad That's OK - I will file mine as a generic code. Maybe useful when reporting data errors, for example if I want to underline the field.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    key = flds[1]
    pos = length(seps[0] flds[1] seps[1]) + 1
    val = substr($0,pos)
    printf "key=<%s>\npos=<%s>\nval=<%s>\n\n", key, pos, val
}
```

```
$ printf -- ' \tFirst \t\t  Second \t Third  \t\n' | awk -f tst.awk
key=<First>
pos=<13>
val=<Second      Third          >

$ printf -- '-11...22;,;..;33-44...;\n' | awk -F'[^0-9-]+' -f tst.awk
key=<-11>
pos=<7>
val=<22;,;..;33-44...;>
```

Comment: perfectly works, upvoted, but accepted another solution because of performance - see my separate answer, thanks

Comment: You specifically asked for `a sane/elegant way`, not `the fastest way possible and it's OK if it only works in specific cases`. @αғsнιη had provided the fastest solution but deleted it when I pointed out that it only works in specific cases but they should probably undelete it as that may be good enough for you. I see you had posted an answer that's since been deleted so I can't comment on it directly but I will say that those results you posted may have been affected by cache-ing and will be affected by the awk version you're running (not all awks only split up to the first referenced field).